# How to allocate an array inside fortran routine "called" from C

Tags: c, memory-management, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I think title says what I need. I know we can use "asd" function to do this, but for some reasons I need to do the allocation in Fortran (i.e. in subroutine "asd_"). Here is the C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void asd(float **c) {
  *c = (float *) malloc (2*sizeof(float));
  **c =123;
  *(*c+1)=1234;
}

void asd_(float **c);

main () {
  float *c;
  asd_(&c);
// asd(&c); would do the job perfectly
  printf("%f %f \n",c[0],c[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

And here is the Fortran code:

```
  subroutine asd(c)

  implicit none

  real, pointer, allocatable ::c(:)

  print *, associated(c)
  if(.not. associated(c))  allocate(c(2))

  end subroutine
```

This randomly gives segmentation fault. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I agree with andrew. I know there is a ISO_C_BINDING module in XL compilers that support interoperability/compatibility between intrinsic C and Fortran types. I believe there is a similar module for gcc. Check this -> http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ISO_005fC_005fBINDING.html

Comment: It is linux. I am using ifort and icc compilers. Anyway, MSB solution works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is also another solution, if you want to use Fortran intrinsic types. This was my case, since I needed to call routines from an external library, using the pre-specified data types. This is basically done with a wrapper Fortran subroutine. Here is the C code:

```
void mywrap_(void **);
void myprint_(void *);

main () {
  void *d;
  mywrap_(&d);
  myprint_(d);
  return 0;
}
```

And here is the wrapper:

```
  subroutine mywrap(b)
  implicit none
  include "h.h"     
  type(st), target, save :: a
  integer, pointer :: b
  interface 
     subroutine alloc(a)
        include "h.h"
        type(st) a
     end subroutine alloc
  end interface

  call alloc(a)
  b => a%i
  end
```

And the Fortran codes:

```
  subroutine alloc(a)
  implicit none 
  include "h.h"
  type(st) a

  a%i = 2
  a%r = 1.5
  if (allocated(a%s)) deallocate(a%s)
  allocate(a%s(2))
  a%s(1) = 1.23
  a%s(2) = 1234
  end
  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  subroutine myprint(a)
  implicit none
  include "h.h"     
  type(st) a

  print *,"INT: ", a%i
  print *,"REAL: ", a%r
  print *,"ALLOC: ", a%s
  end
```

And the header file "h.h":

```
  type st
     sequence
     integer i
     real r
     real, allocatable :: s(:)
  end type
```

Note, this way all the objects are opaque in the C.

Answer (score 10):

The Fortran 2003 ISO C Binding provides a portable way to do this.  It is implemented in many compilers.  Here is example code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test_mem_alloc ( float ** array );

int main ( void ) {

   float * array;
   test_mem_alloc (&array);

   printf ( "Values are: %f %f\n", array [0], array [1] );

   return 0;
}
```

and

```
subroutine test_mem_alloc ( c_array_ptr ) bind (C, name="test_mem_alloc")

   use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
   implicit none

   type (c_ptr), intent (out) :: c_array_ptr
   real (c_float), allocatable, dimension (:), target, save :: FortArray

   allocate (FortArray (1:2) )
   FortArray = [ 2.5_c_float, 4.4_c_float ]

   c_array_ptr = c_loc (FortArray)

end subroutine test_mem_alloc
```

Comment: Nice solution, however, I find the trick with the `save` a little bit a hack: It is not thread safe and also it can not be deallocated again. [In my post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38147004/1859258)  you find a solution, which is based on this one, but fixes those issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a thread safe solution and/or the possibility to deallocate the space from C again, the example below would do the job:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test_mem_alloc(float ** array, void **wrapper);
void free_wrapper(void **wrapper);

int main()
{

  float *array;
  void *wrapper;

  /* Allocates space in Fortran. */
  test_mem_alloc(&array, &wrapper);
  printf( "Values are: %f %f\n", array [0], array [1]);
  /* Deallocates space allocated in Fortran */
  free_wrapper(&wrapper);

  return 0;
}
```

On the Fortran side, you have a general wrapper type `CWrapper`, which can carry any type of derived type. Latter contains the data you would like to pass around. The `CWrapper` type accept arbitrary payload, and you would always invoke the `free_wrapper()` routine from C to release the memory.

```
module memalloc
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
  implicit none

  type :: CWrapper
    class(*), allocatable :: data
  end type CWrapper

  type :: CfloatArray
    real(c_float), allocatable :: array(:)
  end type CfloatArray

contains

  subroutine test_mem_alloc(c_array_ptr, wrapper_ptr)&
      & bind(C, name="test_mem_alloc")
    type (c_ptr), intent (out) :: c_array_ptr
    type(c_ptr), intent(out) :: wrapper_ptr

    type(CWrapper), pointer :: wrapper

    allocate(wrapper)
    allocate(CfloatArray :: wrapper%data)
    select type (data => wrapper%data)
    type is (CfloatArray)
      allocate(data%array(2))
      data%array(:) = [2.5_c_float, 4.4_c_float]
      c_array_ptr = c_loc(data%array)
    end select
    wrapper_ptr = c_loc(wrapper)

  end subroutine test_mem_alloc


  subroutine free_cwrapper(wrapper_ptr) bind(C, name='free_wrapper')
    type(c_ptr), intent(inout) :: wrapper_ptr

    type(CWrapper), pointer :: wrapper

    call c_f_pointer(wrapper_ptr, wrapper)
    deallocate(wrapper)

  end subroutine free_cwrapper

end module memalloc
```